# How do I create a table by using DataFrame & Index

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis

I'm new to Python & want to learn and use it for Data Analysis/Data Science. I'm getting a syntax error.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({‘Q1’:[13000,100,150],‘Q2’:[14000,140,200],‘Q3’:[15000,140,250],‘Q4’[16000,180,300]},index= [‘Imp’,‘Click’,‘Eng’])
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You forgot a colon `'Q4': [16000,180,300]`. And please follow (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to write better questions. You should also format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was with the Quotes that you used in the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"Q1":[13000,100,150],"Q2":[14000,140,200],"Q3":[15000,140,250],"Q4":[16000,180,300]},index= ["Imp","Click","Eng"])

print(df)

          Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4
Imp    13000  14000  15000  16000
Click    100    140    140    180
Eng      150    200    250    300
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @ashish1780 Please accept the answer if it solved the question.